# Get elements inside javascript object that shares similar property names

Tags: javascript, object, extjs, properties, extjs4.2

I want to know if there is a way to ***extract / search*** the elements which contain similar `property` from a javascript object.

Just to be more specific, If I have the following `object`:

***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/sMWUL/

```
var enrolled = {};

enrolled['enrolled/ruby/S1234'] = {
    course: {
        id: 'P01',
        desc: 'Ruby course'
    },
    student: {
        id: 'S1234',
        name: 'John Doe'
    }
};
enrolled['enrolled/php/S1234'] = {
    course: {
        id: 'P02',
        desc: 'PHP course'
    },
    student: {
        id: 'S1234',
        name: 'Foo Bar'
    }
};
enrolled['enrolled/java/S6666'] = {
    course: {
        id: 'P03',
        desc: 'Java course'
    },
    student: {
        id: 'S6666',
        name: 'Bill Gates'
    }
};
```

Then I'll have some similar ***properties*** inside the `enrolled` object (like the ones sharing the ***S1234*** `string` at the end).

---

### So, my question is:

How can I extract the elements with `string` similarities or coincidences in the ***properties***?

I've looked that javascript objects are very limited and the only thing I can do to check if a property exists or not is: `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)` *(but this is not what I am looking for)*. Is there a way to use `regex` to check for this? *(just saying, seems not to be possible).*

Just to know, I am using `ExtJS 4.2` but I can't find something to achieve what I need in the `API` documentation *(correct me if wrong)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for each loop to see if what you're searching for is in the string.`

```
for (key in enrolled)
{
     if(key.indexOf('S1234') > -1)
     {      
         console.log(key);
         //Perform your actions here
     }                 
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/brettwlutz/sMWUL/2/

Comment: That was easy, I tried something like that before but I looked that I made a mistake while retrieving the key. Thanks for giving me the "hint", I finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
for(var prop in enrolled){
console.log(prop);
//check if prop matches string regex.
}
```

Comment: please explain your code and what the questioner was doing wrong ormissing